# Realm.io [java] search by combined field

Tags: java, android, realm

I have User model with Name and Surname properties, and I need query to search by name.
This code is now:

```
query
.beginGroup()
    .contains("name", search, Case.INSENSITIVE)
    .or()
    .contains("surname", search, Case.INSENSITIVE)
.endGroup()
.findAll();
```

But, if i want to search Jerry Smith, i'll write "jerry smi" and won't get what i want, obviously because there's or. How should i do this?

I'm going to create and maintain `fullname` field, setting it on setters of name/surname and search by it, is it good path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to add a third field called "full name" where you put name + surname. Then you'd only search like this:

```
query.contains("full name", search, Case.INSENSITIVE).findAll();
```

Comment: honestly, it sounds like workaround because it needs to be maintained, eg. watching other fields, somehow watch when realm converts object to the model

Comment: the other options is just to divide your "search" by spaces, get the name and surname and search like you did. But you have to make sure that people have no middle names then. But i dont see the problem in this solution that i proposed, why do you think does it need to be maintained?

Comment: how do i get and update this fullname property automatically? put it into setters of name/surname and, if i'm using GSON, manually updating this field everytime i parse?

Comment: well depends on if you're doing the backend too. If yes you can modify it to return that field too, otherwise adding a field while parsing shouldn't be much work i believe.

Comment: the only other option is to have the name and surname separated in your search String i believe.

Comment: @Fen1kz if my answer helped could you upvote it please? Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

```
RealmResults<Event> toEdit = realm.where(Event.class)
        .equalTo("name", day)
        .equalTo("surname", month)
        .findAll();
```

Hope this will help ! Cheers !

Comment: What is Event, day and month? This won't match against `jerry smi`, only complete names